# An unexpected error occurred org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.releaseTag

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

I'm trying to run labkey 19.1 but it's not working.

I have tomcat version 6
Java 11 version
Labkey version 19.1
Running on Linux x64 centos 7.

I'm trying to start tomcat6 (catalina), with java 11 and labkey 19.1 but it failed and I have this error below.

An unexpected error occurred

```
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.releaseTag(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;Z)V
  
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.releaseTag(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;Z)V
  at org.labkey.jsp.compiled.org.labkey.core.view.template.bootstrap.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:271)
  at org.labkey.api.view.JspView.renderView(JspView.java:170)
  at org.labkey.api.view.WebPartView.renderInternal(WebPartView.java:371)
  at org.labkey.api.view.HttpView.render(HttpView.java:132)
  at org.labkey.api.view.HttpView.render(HttpView.java:117)
  at org.labkey.api.view.HttpView.include(HttpView.java:512)
  at org.labkey.api.view.HttpView.include(HttpView.java:489)
  at org.labkey.jsp.compiled.org.labkey.core.view.template.bootstrap.pageTemplate_jsp._jspService(pageTemplate_jsp.java:204)
  at org.labkey.api.view.JspView.renderView(JspView.java:170)
  at org.labkey.api.view.WebPartView.renderInternal(WebPartView.java:371)
  at org.labkey.api.view.HttpView.render(HttpView.java:132)
  at org.labkey.api.view.HttpView.render(HttpView.java:117)
  at org.labkey.api.action.SpringActionController.renderInTemplate(SpringActionController.java:615)
  at org.labkey.api.action.SpringActionController.handleRequest(SpringActionController.java:495)
  at org.labkey.api.module.DefaultModule.dispatch(DefaultModule.java:1265)
  at org.labkey.api.view.ViewServlet._service(ViewServlet.java:204)
  at org.labkey.api.view.ViewServlet.service(ViewServlet.java:131)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.labkey.api.data.TransactionFilter.doFilter(TransactionFilter.java:38)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.labkey.api.module.ModuleLoader.doFilter(ModuleLoader.java:1220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.labkey.api.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:215)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.labkey.core.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
  request attributes
  LABKEY.OriginalURL = https://localhost/labkey/project/home/begin.view?
  LABKEY.StartTime = 1623203147397
  LABKEY.action = begin
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.CONTEXT = Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 08 21:42:11 EDT 2021]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
  LABKEY.controller = project
  LABKEY.Counter = 0
  X-LABKEY-CSRF = 682372b1fa32a0fa942abc32c0d07ddf
  LABKEY.container = /home
  LABKEY.RequestURL = /labkey/project/home/begin.view?
  LABKEY.OriginalURLHelper = /labkey/project/home/begin.view?
```

I have tried to update java to java 12 and the issue is still there, I also upgraded labkey to 19.3 the issue is still there, I'm not sure why it keeps saying this error and prevent the tomcat to start.

The weird part is that labkey 18.3 is working, the issue only appears when upgrading to labkey 19.1 or later.

Comment: Tomcat 6 saw its [end of life](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html) in 2016. Java 11 was released in 2018. Not many will have ever attempted to run both together. You really should keep an eye on your infrastructure and keep it somewhat up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded tomcat 6 to tomcat 9 and it fixed the problem,

The issue was not in java or labkey, it was tomcat that needed to be updated.